# hive schema on json file

Tags: json, hive, jsonschema

I am working on hive schema to create the hive table from SampleRecord.json file.

please find the sample of my json file as below:-

```
[
    {
        "path":"C:/Logs/OCJKLCM-01A/ABCD$/jkgM/Diagnostics/2017-06-
                 27/BOSS3.000.log",
        "@timestamp":"2017-07-18T07:05:55.9650000Z",
        "roadd":"BEL",
        "@version":"1",
        "host":"jkgMONEDev",
        "source":"CCM",
        "message":"06/27/2017 05:00:02.4188801 UTC-03:00,
            Info,
            Link,
            TX,
            BEL.l.BEL.5307:ibm,
            BEL.b:03.0003,
            2080,
            956301323,
            04-08-20-04-11-00-00-3B-39-00-00-0B-59-52-10-7C-25-01-2C-00-28-6D-72-73-
            2E-6C-2E-6D-72-73-2E-35-33-30-37-3A-69-74-63-00-6D-72-73-2E-62-3A-30-33-
            2E-30-30-30-33-00-4D-52-53-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-
            00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-A4-00-19-5C-1F-40-
            E7-A9-BC-67-F1-8E-85-71-02-09-02-07-02-00-00-00-00-0A-F0-29-2C\r",
        "type":"CCM",
        "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2017-07-19T11:33:42.1153239Z",
        "PartitionId":0,
        "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2017-07-18T07:05:56.8450000Z"
    }
]
```

There will be multiple {},{} like this.

Please help me to create the hive schema for this sample JSON.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be specific when you ask questions, showing your (related!) code, what the problem is, what you tried to fix it, what you got and what you expected instead. In your case, please also define a question/problem your trying to solve.